# Handling Paypal payment status 'Completed-Funds-Held' with time-sensitive goods

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

Good morning, I'm working with `DoExpressCheckout`'s Payment Status response for an `InstantPaymentOnly` `Sale`.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

By `PAYMENTINFO_n_PAYMENTSTATUS` all possible responses are shown, `Completed-Funds-Held` is the latest addition.

I'm providing a service that expires and must be used by a certain time. If the payments final status is not known by the time the service must start, its looks like we're going to have to collect payment (again) in person and refund the online payment. Needless to say, that doesn't sound good.

**Q.** Could `Completed-Funds-Held` result in funds never being deposited to the main balance?

The documentation for that particular status lists two possible response codes that go along with `Completed-Funds-Held`: `newsellerpaymenthold` (not applicable in my case) and `paymenthold` which vaguely states "*A hold is placed on the merchant's transaction for a reason not listed*."

Basically is `Completed-Funds-Held` a "successful" transaction where the purchaser can receive his product without risk of the seller never receiving payment?

EDIT: Is `Completed-Funds-Held` a final status if the payment is successful? Or will a `Completed` IPN request come if and when the hold is settled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those payments will eventually become available.  What you should do is setup an [IPN solution](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) so that you can automatically update your system when a payment hold is released.  The same would be true for things like e-checks where the payment status is simply pending and then clears a few days later.

Comment: Thanks, I have a payment flow with IPN enabled, useraction set to commit. If I can verify the transaction is/will complete I'd like to show the user "order confirmed/complete" right away instead of "pending". Would I be correct in checking for a response of either "Completed" or "Completed-Funds-Held" as absolute verification?

Comment: There are quite a few different values that could come back for the payment status at that point based on the way the user paid, your seller settings, how you were vetted when PayPal opened the account, etc.  Personally, I like to let IPN handle all of that because it happens in real-time and it's always accurate.